# How to get the screenshot of the form

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Any method to output the screenshot of an active form?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Even simpler answer supported by .NET:

[Control.DrawToBitmap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.drawtobitmap.aspx).

Comment: what if you want to capture any dialog boxes that may be open at the time? or overlapping Forms. You won't be seeing the application as it really is on the users screen I think.

Comment: This method has some limitations (most notably that child controls are drawn in reverse order), I've posted an answer that does not have that problem.

Answer (score 32):

Use the Control.DrawToBitmap() method.  For example:

```
    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        var frm = Form.ActiveForm;
        using (var bmp = new Bitmap(frm.Width, frm.Height)) {
            frm.DrawToBitmap(bmp, new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height));
            bmp.Save(@"c:\temp\screenshot.png");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;

namespace ScreenshotCapturer
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private static Bitmap bmpScreenshot;
        private static Graphics gfxScreenshot;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnCapture_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // If the user has choosed a path where to save the screenshot
            if (saveScreenshot.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                // Hide the form so that it does not appear in the screenshot
                this.Hide();
                // Set the bitmap object to the size of the screen
                bmpScreenshot = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
                // Create a graphics object from the bitmap
                gfxScreenshot = Graphics.FromImage(bmpScreenshot);
                // Take the screenshot from the upper left corner to the right bottom corner
                gfxScreenshot.CopyFromScreen(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.X, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Y, 0, 0, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Size, CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);
                // Save the screenshot to the specified path that the user has chosen
                bmpScreenshot.Save(saveScreenshot.FileName, ImageFormat.Png);
                // Show the form again
                this.Show();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: where does this ScreenCapture class come from? It's not part of the .NET framework...

Answer (score 2):

Here's an extension method you can use:

```
    #region Interop

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint msg, IntPtr hdc, PRF_FLAGS drawingOptions);

    const uint WM_PRINT = 0x317;

    [Flags]
    enum PRF_FLAGS : uint
    {
        CHECKVISIBLE = 0x01,
        CHILDREN = 0x02,
        CLIENT = 0x04,
        ERASEBKGND = 0x08,
        NONCLIENT = 0x10,
        OWNED = 0x20
    }

    #endregion

    public static Image CaptureImage(this Control control)
    {
        Image img = new Bitmap(control.Width, control.Height);
        using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(img))
        {
            SendMessage(
               control.Handle,
               WM_PRINT,
               g.GetHdc(),
               PRF_FLAGS.CLIENT | PRF_FLAGS.NONCLIENT | PRF_FLAGS.ERASEBKGND);
        }
        return img;
    }
```

`Form` inherits from `Control`, so you can use it on a form too.

Comment: This appears to function the same as Control.DrawToBitmap, with the same limitations (like child controls being drawn in reverse order).

Answer (score 2):

Because Control.DrawToBitmap has some limitations (most notably drawing child controls in reverse order) I have made this alternative. The variable `_control` is the WinForms Control/Form that you want to copy.

```
using (Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(width, height)) {
    using (Graphics gb = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
    using (Graphics gc = Graphics.FromHwnd(_control.Handle)) {

          IntPtr hdcDest = IntPtr.Zero;
          IntPtr hdcSrc = IntPtr.Zero;

          try {
              hdcDest = gb.GetHdc();
              hdcSrc = gc.GetHdc();

              BitBlt(hdcDest, 0, 0, width, height, hdcSrc, 0, 0, SRC_COPY);
          } finally {
              if (hdcDest != IntPtr.Zero) gb.ReleaseHdc(hdcDest);
              if (hdcSrc != IntPtr.Zero) gc.ReleaseHdc(hdcSrc);
          }
      }

      bitmap.Save(...);
}

[DllImport("gdi32.dll", EntryPoint = "BitBlt")]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
public static extern bool BitBlt(
    [In()] System.IntPtr hdc, int x, int y, int cx, int cy,
    [In()] System.IntPtr hdcSrc, int x1, int y1, uint rop);

private const int SRC_COPY = 0xCC0020;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
         this.Opacity = 0;
        Rectangle bounds = Screen.GetBounds(Point.Empty);

        // create the bitmap to copy the screen shot to
        Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(bounds.Width, bounds.Height);

        // now copy the screen image to the graphics device from the bitmap
        using (Graphics gr = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
        {

            gr.CopyFromScreen(Point.Empty, Point.Empty, bounds.Size);          
        }
        this.Opacity = 100;
```

Now just

```
        gr.Save(@"c\pic.jpg",ImageFormat.jpg);
```

Comment: I believe you've miss read the question. The question states "screenshot of an active form" while your solution captures the whole screen leaving the active form out of it. I believe you can easily turn it to what the question asks for.

Answer (score 1):

This will save a screenshot of your active window to your C: drive.

The `SendKeys.Send("")` is used to send keypresses to the computer. In this case `%` is used to press `Alt` and `{PRTSC}` obviously to press the `Print Screen` button on your keyboard.

Hope this helps someone!

```
private void printScreenButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SendKeys.Send("%{PRTSC}");
    Image img = Clipboard.GetImage();
    img.Save(@"C:\\testprintscreen.jpg");
}
```

Comment: It also destroys anything that was held on the clipboard, which might get in the way of what the user was doing.

Answer (score 1):

```
here is:




       public const int SRCCOPY = 0x00CC0020; // BitBlt dwRop parameter

    [DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
    public static extern bool BitBlt(IntPtr hObject, int nXDest, int nYDest,
        int nWidth, int nHeight, IntPtr hObjectSource,
        int nXSrc, int nYSrc, int dwRop);

    [DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
    public static extern bool StretchBlt(
          IntPtr hdcDest,      // handle to destination DC
          int nXOriginDest, // x-coord of destination upper-left corner
          int nYOriginDest, // y-coord of destination upper-left corner
          int nWidthDest,   // width of destination rectangle
          int nHeightDest,  // height of destination rectangle
          IntPtr hdcSrc,       // handle to source DC
          int nXOriginSrc,  // x-coord of source upper-left corner
          int nYOriginSrc,  // y-coord of source upper-left corner
          int nWidthSrc,    // width of source rectangle
          int nHeightSrc,   // height of source rectangle
          int dwRop       // raster operation code
        );


    [DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr CreateCompatibleBitmap(IntPtr hDC, int nWidth,
        int nHeight);
    [DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr CreateCompatibleDC(IntPtr hDC);
    [DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
    public static extern bool DeleteDC(IntPtr hDC);
    [DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
    public static extern bool DeleteObject(IntPtr hObject);
    [DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr SelectObject(IntPtr hDC, IntPtr hObject);



    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct RECT
    {
        public int left;
        public int top;
        public int right;
        public int bottom;
    }

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr GetDesktopWindow();
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr GetWindowDC(IntPtr hWnd);
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr ReleaseDC(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hDC);
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr GetWindowRect(IntPtr hWnd, ref RECT rect);

    private void run_test()
    {

        Rectangle rc = new Rectangle();
        Image img = ScreenToImage(ref rc, false);
        img.Save(@"C:\Users\ssaamm\Desktop\Capt44ure.JPG", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        img.Dispose();

    }


    private Image ScreenToImage(ref Rectangle rcDest, bool IsPapaer)
    {
        IntPtr handle = this.Handle;

        //this.Handle
        // get te hDC of the target window
        IntPtr hdcSrc = GetWindowDC(handle);
        // get the size
        RECT windowRect = new RECT();
        GetWindowRect(handle, ref windowRect);
        int nWidth = windowRect.right - windowRect.left;
        int nHeight = windowRect.bottom - windowRect.top;

        if (IsPapaer)
        {
            float fRate = (float)rcDest.Width / nWidth;
            //float fHeight = nHeight * fRate;
            //rcDest.Height = (int)(nHeight * fRate);
            //rcDest.Width = (int)(rcDest.Width);// * fRate);
            rcDest.X = 0;
            rcDest.Y = 0;
            rcDest.Height = (int)(nHeight * fRate);
            //rcDest.Width = (int)(nWidth * fRate);
        }
        else
        {
            rcDest.X = 0;
            rcDest.Y = 0;
            rcDest.Height = nHeight;
            rcDest.Width = nWidth;
        }

        // create a device context we can copy to
        IntPtr hdcDest = CreateCompatibleDC(hdcSrc);
        // create a bitmap we can copy it to,
        // using GetDeviceCaps to get the width/height
        IntPtr hBitmap = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdcSrc, rcDest.Width, rcDest.Height);
        // select the bitmap object
        IntPtr hOld = SelectObject(hdcDest, hBitmap);
        // bitblt over
        StretchBlt(hdcDest, rcDest.X, rcDest.Y, rcDest.Width, rcDest.Height, hdcSrc, 0, 0, nWidth, nHeight, SRCCOPY);
        // restore selection
        SelectObject(hdcDest, hOld);
        // clean up 
        DeleteDC(hdcDest);
        ReleaseDC(handle, hdcSrc);

        // get a .NET image object for it
        Image img = Image.FromHbitmap(hBitmap);
        // free up the Bitmap object
        DeleteObject(hBitmap);
        return img;
    }
```